# Auto propagation of formulas down the columns for each new row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

How to propagate those formulas down the respective colums for every new row automatically? There is an webhook which creates new rows with data with those columns (A1, X2, Y2) empty, and I would need them to auto propagate when the new row appears. Can I use VBA to put the formula in place when triggered by a new row?

A1 — =IF(C1="TOTAL", X1, Y1)

X2 — =IF(C2="TOTAL", IF(AND(C1="TOTAL", D1=D2), X1, X1+1), X1)

Y2 — =IF(C2="TOTAL", Y1, Y1+1)

Comment: What array formulas have you tried?

Comment: For example =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C1="TOTAL", X1, Y1))

Comment: @Marcin, I'm not sure if you actually type "ARRAYFORMULA" into the cell, so to eliminate that possibility right away please confirm that you enter the formula by Pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html